# how to display records that are only connected to a single user

Tags: associations, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I hope you can help me here.

I want the users only to be able to see the appointments to the courses they are assigned to. How do I set it up in the controllers?

I got 3 models:

```
class Appointment < ActiveRecord::Base  
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :course
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base  
  has_many :courses, :through => :assignments
  has_many :appointments
end

class Course < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users, :through => :assignments
  has_many :appointments
end
```

Comment: Which model does has_many :appointments refer to?

Comment: Hi it refers to Class Appointment. I had it misspelled thanks. I ve changed it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should just be able to do:

```
@appointments = current_user.appointments
```

Or am I missing something in your question?

---

*Edit:* A more detailed example:

In your controller (let's say it's AppointmentsController):

```
class AppointmentsController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @appointments = current_user.appointments
  end

end
```

Then, in the corresponding view (appointments/index.html.erb):

```
<%- @appointments.each do |appointment| -%>
  <%= appointment.name %>
<%- end -%>
```

This is all based on the assumption you have current_user available, but since you've tagged the question with 'devise', I'm assuming you do.

Comment: can you tell me how I can use it?

Comment: I've updated my answer with a more detailed example, but this is really basic rails stuff.. If you're unfamiliar with it, check out some of the many, many tutorials out there about getting started with rails.

Answer (score 0):

I want to add to idlefingers' answer that you should recheck those relationships between the courses and the users. It seems a bit weird having at both sides has_many. Use has_many_and_belongs_to